# Can't make WhiteNoise work with Django & Heroku for production

Tags: django, python-3.x, heroku, production-environment, production

I'm trying to reproduce a production website on Heroku, and to do that I followed step-by-step these 3 guides below:

- http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Deployment
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets

Since I'm using Django 1.11, I don't know if I need to do something different from these guides.

Part of my production.py(same as settings.py but only for production) looks like this:

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))

DEBUG = bool( os.environ.get('DJANGO_DEBUG', True) )

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['(((MY WEBSITE))).herokuapp.com']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
# 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

And the bottom of production.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

CORS_REPLACE_HTTPS_REFERER      = True
HOST_SCHEME                     = "https://"
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER         = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT             = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE           = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE              = True
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS  = True
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS             = 1000000
SECURE_FRAME_DENY               = True

SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF     = True
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER       = True
SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD             = True
X_FRAME_OPTIONS                 = 'DENY'

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

Everything works fine when the `DEBUG = True`, but when I set `DEBUG = False` I get a *Server Error (500)* meaning it's something wrong with Django and/or WhiteNoise while handling the staticfiles but I really don't know where is the problem.

Other relevant files:
*Procfile* (required for heroku)

```
web: gunicorn (((MY WEBSITE))).wsgi --log-file -
```

*wsgi.py*

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "(((MY WEBSITE))).settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Last push:

```
((((MY WEBSITE)))) PS C:\users\Luis\Dev\(((MY WEBSITE)))\src> git push heroku master
Counting objects: 15, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (14/14), done.
Writing objects: 100% (15/15), 1.76 KiB | 1.76 MiB/s, done.
Total 15 (delta 9), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:
remote: -----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote:        180 static files copied to '/tmp/build_f959f2c0c358dd398ff8dc5e3868dcdf/staticfiles', 194 post-processed
remote:
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 114.6M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v30
remote:        https://(((MY WEBSITE))).herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https:// git.heroku.com/(((MY WEBSITE))).git
   4accd59..f3ec57d  master -> master
((((MY WEBSITE)))) PS C:\users\Luis\Dev\(((MY WEBSITE)))\src> heroku config:set DJANGO_DEBUG=''
Setting DJANGO_DEBUG and restarting (((MY WEBSITE)))... done, v31
```

(from Windows 10 PowerShell)

I can provide any additional info.

Edit 1: Heroku logs

```
((((MY WEBSITE)))) PS C:\users\Luis\Dev\(((MY WEBSITE)))\src> heroku logs

...

2017-10-12T15:37:30.520087+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2017-10-12T15:37:30.520672+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2017-10-12T15:37:29.813498+00:00 app[api]: Release v33 created by user (((MY EMAIL)))@gmail.com
2017-10-12T15:37:29.813498+00:00 app[api]: Set DJANGO_DEBUG config vars by user (((MY EMAIL)))@gmail.com
2017-10-12T15:37:31.361203+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2017-10-12T15:37:31.381777+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-10-12 15:37:31 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2017-10-12T15:37:31.384572+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-10-12 15:37:31 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
2017-10-12T15:37:31.384240+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-10-12 15:37:31 +0000] [4] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2017-10-12T15:37:31.803827+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-10-12 15:37:31 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2017-10-12T15:37:32.395851+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2017-10-12T15:37:37.767520+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn (((MY WEBSITE))).wsgi --log-file -`
2017-10-12T15:37:40.329480+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-10-12 15:37:40 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
2017-10-12T15:37:40.329980+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-10-12 15:37:40 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:35812 (4)
2017-10-12T15:37:40.330075+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-10-12 15:37:40 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2017-10-12T15:37:40.333422+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-10-12 15:37:40 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
2017-10-12T15:37:40.400345+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-10-12 15:37:40 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2017-10-12T15:37:41.576143+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-10-12T15:37:50.369924+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/images/portfolio/big1.jpg" host=(((MY WEBSITE))).herokuapp.com request_id=ec600bfe-db53-4133-9964-76ec4b01fa06 fwd="186.242.96.167" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=67ms status=200 bytes=1534224 protocol=https
2017-10-12T15:37:50.697986+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/images/portfolio/big9.jpg" host=(((MY WEBSITE))).herokuapp.com request_id=7a74a519-106e-46a1-9714-8a4f60f9f919 fwd="186.242.96.167" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=100ms status=200 bytes=1262299 protocol=https
2017-10-12T15:37:50.768865+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/images/portfolio/big4.jpg" host=(((MY WEBSITE))).herokuapp.com request_id=fb430cc6-843d-43df-ab0b-b8840c0fd587 fwd="186.242.96.167" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=166ms status=200 bytes=1405390 protocol=https
2017-10-12T15:37:50.672386+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/images/portfolio/big5.jpg" host=(((MY WEBSITE))).herokuapp.com request_id=70c1a959-a2be-40f0-a4e5-6da60895e3dd fwd="186.242.96.167" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=80ms status=200 bytes=1221233 protocol=https
2017-10-12T15:37:50.749487+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/images/portfolio/big8.jpg" host=(((MY WEBSITE))).herokuapp.com request_id=e72091eb-a9f3-4b69-8f78-eba9fb5e826a fwd="186.242.96.167" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=141ms status=200 bytes=1239167 protocol=https
2017-10-12T15:37:50.720786+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/images/portfolio/big7.jpg" host=(((MY WEBSITE))).herokuapp.com request_id=1dc85d82-b8b9-4d35-b461-bdec2181b0cf fwd="186.242.96.167" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=116ms status=200 bytes=1228519 protocol=https
2017-10-12T15:37:50.783929+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/images/portfolio/big2.jpg" host=(((MY WEBSITE))).herokuapp.com request_id=dc430a8f-8d01-4ee2-a26b-9fadd00f6f5b fwd="186.242.96.167" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=171ms status=200 bytes=1515225 protocol=https
2017-10-12T15:37:50.738707+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/images/portfolio/big3.jpg" host=(((MY WEBSITE))).herokuapp.com request_id=7158de90-258f-43ec-a974-edc1b3ae0039 fwd="186.242.96.167" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=143ms status=200 bytes=1656610 protocol=https
2017-10-12T15:37:50.851201+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/images/portfolio/big6.jpg" host=(((MY WEBSITE))).herokuapp.com request_id=6128369a-560a-41e4-bb0e-990473935a85 fwd="186.242.96.167" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=233ms status=200 bytes=1238918 protocol=https
2017-10-12T15:37:52.202544+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/images/portfolio/big10.jpg" host=(((MY WEBSITE))).herokuapp.com request_id=8fed9a74-56d4-4458-ad67-b906ba4534ce fwd="186.242.96.167" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=47ms status=200 bytes=1321351 protocol=https
2017-10-12T15:37:52.845341+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/images/portfolio/big12.jpg" host=(((MY WEBSITE))).herokuapp.com request_id=752a5b5d-1a99-4908-9c89-7d539f90c0ba fwd="186.242.96.167" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=46ms status=200 bytes=1469642 protocol=https
2017-10-12T15:37:52.814850+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/images/portfolio/big11.jpg" host=(((MY WEBSITE))).herokuapp.com request_id=7042189d-0303-47d6-827b-4943ae2d9d20 fwd="186.242.96.167" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=40ms status=200 bytes=1313499 protocol=https
2017-10-12T15:39:31.770328+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=(((MY WEBSITE))).herokuapp.com request_id=78b9aa71-a519-4636-b267-272393570c04 fwd="186.242.96.167" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=78ms status=500 bytes=228 protocol=https
```

Comment: What does the Heroku log show when you get that 500?

Comment: I just set `heroku config:set DJANGO_DEBUG=''` to make `DEBUG=False` and Shift+F5 (hard refresh) the page, and this is what I got(see above).

Comment: But you said you got a 500 error, where is that?

Comment: Well, it's showing on my browser _Server Error (500)_ everytime I refresh. If there is another location to get more accurate logs, let me know. I'm new in this.

Comment: How do I make `DEBUG = TRUE` while WhiteNoise handles the staticfiles? Cause I tried to follow this guide: [using-whitenoise-in-development](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/latest/django.html#using-whitenoise-in-development) and didn't give me a Server Error (500). I'm kinda lost right now.

Comment: Only difference I see between your config and my working app is that I'm using:

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'

Also, Whitenoise will handle files in DEBUG mode only if you include it in your INSTALLED_APPS  list as 'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic'

Comment: I already tried this, but didn't work. I saw older guides using this GzipManifest, so I think it's related to older versions of Django/Whitenoise. With `whitenoise.runserver_nostatic` on everything went fine, meaning that is possible a Django problem.

Answer (score 0):

This line jumped out at me as looking wrong:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/var/www/static/',
]
```

Where did that `/var/www/static` line come from? All those paths are supposed to be directories within your project where Django should look for static files. That directory won't exist on Heroku and is probably what causes Django to throw an error.

Comment: Indeed it is wrong, was commented and pasting here somewhat got uncommented. Updated the main post, sorry about that. _Server Error (500)_ still happening though. :(

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should comment in 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware' in middleware and after it comment out the

## STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

This (STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage') does encounter the server error.
After it you should run the following command in you terminal or bash:
python manage.py collectstatic
This will make copies of all static files from static folder to staticfiles folder which will serve in you browser as static files.